# Disable group chat notifications with Focus mode, even from allowed people

Tags: ios, messages, notifications, focus

iOS 15 has a Focus feature that lets you disable all notifications except for a list of specific people. I've added one person to it.

Unfortunately, when this persons sends a message to a group chat or even uses the quick "like"/"haha" responses in the group chat, these notifications get through the Focus mode.

Is there a way to use Focus to allow notifications from specific people, **only if they call/message me directly**? In other words: use Focus mode to mute notifications from group chats where there are participants not in the list of allowed notifications.